# How to Cronjob to run specific function every 21 days using node-cron node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to check the cron to run every 21days. I am getting every 21st day only using the mentioned Cron expression. Can somebody help me to sort this out?

```
  try {
    var interval = parser.parseExpression('00 12 12 21 * *');

    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
  }
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! I'm not sure what's the issue here, you're saying you're already getting every 21st day using a specific expression. If this already works, what do you need help with?

Comment: I need it to be every 21 days not the 21st day of a month. If suppose today is 30-09-2019 after 21days will be 21-10-2019 and after that need to be 11-11-2019.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run at 00:00 every 21st day of the month:
`0 0 21 * *` (at 00:00 on day-of-month 21).

If you want it to run at 12:00 every 21st day of the month:
`0 12 21 * *` (at 12:00 on day-of-month 21).

If you want it to run every 21 days, no matter the day of month, then I'm afraid that's not possible using node-cron and also most other similar scheduling systems.

In that specific case you'd have to track the days yourself and calculate the next day it should run at by adding 21 days to the current date whenever the function runs.

If you want to play around with cron schedules, I recommend [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_12_21_*_*).

If you want to add the 21 days yourself, you can use setInterval to schedule a function to run at a specific time:

```js
const waitSeconds = 1814400; // 21 days

function scheduledFunction() {
  // Do something
}

// Run now
scheduledFunction();

// Run every 21 days
setInterval(scheduledFunction, waitSeconds);
```

However, keep in mind that the internal clock might be inaccurate so there can be quite a few seconds of difference.

Comment: Yes, I too think like that. But how to do the manual calculation?

Comment: @AJITHKUMAR.J I've added some example code to my answer.

Comment: It will work every 21days interval but we cannot able to specify which time to execute on the 21st day right? Usually, it will calculate from the current time, isn't it?

Comment: @AJITHKUMAR.J you are right, my code would always add 21 days to the current time. You can take the current time into account though and recalculate the `waitSeconds` every time to run the function at a specific time.

Comment: @AJITHKUMAR.J It would help me a lot if you'd accept my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

this can help you

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

try{
cron.schedule(* * 21 * *, () =>{
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
    })
}catch(err){
console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
}
}
```

The `21` means `21th` of every `month`
you can all so check https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron for better understanding

Comment: The node-cron documentation states the allowed range for seconds and minutes to be `0-59`. Your code will throw "30240 is a invalid expression for minute".